# Odd behaviour with Unevictable cache (Linux kernel)

Tags: cache, linux-kernel, memory-management

I'm seeing a behaviour I cannot explain on my embedded Linux target (initramfs and **no swapping**).

As there is no swapping, I would expect anything in /tmp (tmpfs) to be flagged unevictable. Instead, I'm observing the following when using the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
count=1
while true; do
    echo "#$count"
    dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zero$count bs=1M count=10 && cat /proc/meminfo | grep 'Unevictable\|Shmem'
    count=`expr $count + 1`
    sleep 3
done
```

- If writing many files of 10MB, the Shmem grows linearly but the unevictable memory jumps from 0KB to ~200MB very quickly:

  ```
  #40
  10+0 records in
  10+0 records out
  10485760 bytes (10.0MB) copied, 0.102484 seconds, 97.6MB/s
  Unevictable:           0 kB
  Shmem:            453776 kB
  #41
  10+0 records in
  10+0 records out
  10485760 bytes (10.0MB) copied, 0.047640 seconds, 209.9MB/s
  Unevictable:           0 kB
  Shmem:            464196 kB
  #42
  10+0 records in
  10+0 records out
  10485760 bytes (10.0MB) copied, 0.101833 seconds, 98.2MB/s
  Unevictable:         884 kB
  Shmem:            474616 kB
  #43
  10+0 records in
  10+0 records out
  10485760 bytes (10.0MB) copied, 0.051686 seconds, 193.5MB/s
  Unevictable:      234612 kB
  Shmem:            485040 kB
  #44
  10+0 records in
  10+0 records out
  10485760 bytes (10.0MB) copied, 0.052157 seconds, 191.7MB/s
  Unevictable:      238568 kB
  Shmem:            495572 kB
  #45
  10+0 records in
  10+0 records out
  10485760 bytes (10.0MB) copied, 0.043332 seconds, 230.8MB/s
  Unevictable:      245332 kB
  Shmem:            505892 kB
  #46
  10+0 records in
  10+0 records out
  10485760 bytes (10.0MB) copied, 0.042653 seconds, 234.4MB/s
  Unevictable:      245332 kB
  Shmem:            516312 kB
  #47
  10+0 records in
  10+0 records out
  10485760 bytes (10.0MB) copied, 0.048478 seconds, 206.3MB/s
  Unevictable:      248384 kB
  Shmem:            526724 kB
  ```
- If I delete all the zero files, the unevictable memory stays at the same level. Does it mean I lost all that RAM? It looks like it as the OOM killer seems to be invoked earlier. How can I reclaim it?

  ```
  # rm /tmp/zero*
  # cat /proc/meminfo | grep 'Unevictable\|Shmem'
  Unevictable:      288372 kB
  Shmem:             48412 kB
  ```
- With chunks of 100MB instead of 10MB:

  ```
  #1
  100+0 records in
  100+0 records out
  104857600 bytes (100.0MB) copied, 0.422820 seconds, 236.5MB/s
  Unevictable:           0 kB
  Shmem:            150168 kB
  #2
  100+0 records in
  100+0 records out
  104857600 bytes (100.0MB) copied, 0.471385 seconds, 212.1MB/s
  Unevictable:           0 kB
  Shmem:            252516 kB
  #3
  100+0 records in
  100+0 records out
  104857600 bytes (100.0MB) copied, 0.444059 seconds, 225.2MB/s
  Unevictable:           0 kB
  Shmem:            354888 kB
  #4
  100+0 records in
  100+0 records out
  104857600 bytes (100.0MB) copied, 0.414981 seconds, 241.0MB/s
  Unevictable:           0 kB
  Shmem:            457368 kB
  #5
  100+0 records in
  100+0 records out
  104857600 bytes (100.0MB) copied, 5.538392 seconds, 18.1MB/s
  Unevictable:      288264 kB
  Shmem:            559700 kB
  #6
  dd: writing '/tmp/zero6': No space left on device
  ```

Can someone explain the observed behaviour, which looks like a Kernel bug to me.

Thank you

Comment: I think it's by design: `tmpfs` discs are allowed to grow, up to their specified limit, but file space is not released automatically. It can be released manually with `mount -o remount`, as in [this link](https://linuxraj.wordpress.com/2015/11/24/how-to-modify-the-size-of-tmpfs/). I'm not sure that the unevictable memory you observe is allocated to `tmpfs`: without a swap area **all** memory is effectively unevictable, but isn't necessarily flagged as such - `tmpfs` discs are normally swappable when a swap area has been defined.

Comment: Is it possible that the unevictable pages are calculated on the first cache reclaim (for some performance reasons)? It correlates my different tests. As you confirmed, without any swap everything become unevictable so it should contain the root system (initramfs) and the shmem. Although, it doesn't seem to grow linear with shmem.

Comment: For what it's worth, on my disc-based system with swap, I have 5 `tmpfs` partitions containing 63MB of files, but only 48KB of unevictable memory, the same as the Mlocked size. You could compare your unevictable memory with other memory allocations in `/proc/meminfo` before and after it has grown: this may shed light on why it's suddenly so high.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is not a tmpfs - but a ramfs.

> The unevictable list addresses the following classes of unevictable
>   pages:
>
> - Those owned by ramfs.
> - Those mapped into `SHM_LOCK`'d shared memory regions.
> - Those mapped into `VM_LOCKED` [mlock()ed] VMAs.
>
> The infrastructure may also be able to handle other conditions that
>   make pages unevictable, either by definition or by circumstance, in
>   the future.
>
> https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/unevictable-lru.txt

In answer to your question, [Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-proc-meminfo) summarize "Unevictable" as "The amount of memory, in kibibytes, **discovered by the pageout code**, that is not evictable because it is locked into memory by user programs."

Reading the full doc, it sounds like for some reason `ramfs` allocations start off on the normal `Inactive(anon)` LRU list.  Once you run out of free memory and start triggering reclaim (pageout), the lists are scanned, and the VM will "discover" the the locked memory and move it to the unevictable list.

On a related note, there is also a [kernel comment](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.17/source/include/linux/mmzone.h#L142) which suggests the "Mlocked" field might not account for  locked pages immediately.  (Maybe it will in some cases, I haven't checked).

```
NR_MLOCK,       /* mlock()ed pages found and moved off LRU */
```

I'm not assuming the kernel scans the entire list at once, but I expect it scans it in large batches.

The problem with this theory is I don't know why/how your kernel would scan the "anon" lists, if you don't have any swap configured.  I even found the [code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/mm/vmscan.c#L2297) -

```
/* If we have no swap space, do not bother scanning anon pages. */
if (!sc->may_swap || mem_cgroup_get_nr_swap_pages(memcg) <= 0) {
    scan_balance = SCAN_FILE;
    goto out;
}
```